# Automating Pulse Audio Volume Control toggle config on off on Kubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, kde, alsa

On Kubuntu 20.10, my audio works fine if I use the Display port out to my GPU from my display, but if use my Mobo backpanel, I need to restart the device first. I don't want to use the GPU because it doesn't work when I switch to my hackintosh, so I want to create an crontab script to fix it.

I've tried restarting pulse audio and pulseaudio -k, but these do not consistently fix it (they seem to work the first couple of reboots, and then stop working). The most consistent fix is opening the pulse audio control gui app, and toggling the device in the config tab. [gui app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSfHq.png)

I've tried automating with GUI app automators, but it's slow and annoying. Does anyone have an idea of what Pulse Audio Volume control is doing when it toggles that config and how to do the same from the command line?

I tried looking at the source code, but I don't know C++, and I suspect the better way would be via a better understanding of pulse audio itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pulse audio does write a file called cookie that blocks audio output device switching in some applications, for example it blocks Firefox from changing audio output device while the rest of the OS does change the audio output on request.

To remove that file run $ `rm ~/.config/pulse/cookie` and the output device can be switched again. This will allow to change devices again.

In Gnome Extensions there is an extension called: "Sound Input & Output Device Chooser", this does add the output device switch option to the taskbar. Most likely there will be an extension for this in KDE.